# pass data from my input box to controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, controller

```
<div id="dtBasicExample_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">Box #</div>
                <div class="col-md-8"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Box #" style="width:350px;"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></div>
            </div>
```

My controller code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddBoxForm(String boxID)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(boxID)
        return View();
    }
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `name` to your `input` and change your `button` to submit type `input`.

Here is a working demo like below:

```
<form asp-action="AddBoxForm" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">Box #</div>
    <div class="col-md-8"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="boxID" placeholder="Box #" style="width:350px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="save" /></div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]